# Client side thumb creation OR Server side?

Tags: image, client

Hy,

I have two options to choose from:
Client side(with FLASH or Javascript):
 **pro:** image manipulations occurs on the client side, so no load on the server
 **cons:** more uploaded data

Server side(Ruby on rails):
 **pro:** less uploaded data
 **cons:** image manipulations occurs on the server side, so there are some load and will be queried...

For example, when you upload an image, you will get 4 images: a large image, medium, thumb1, thumb2, so in the case of the client side will be needed to upload the 4 optimized images. For the server side, will be only uploaded 1 optimized image and then manipulated.

What is better and less consuming way?

EDIT:
On server side: I really do not know these details but will be used ruby on rails.

The only thing I wanted to know if is more consuming:
1) load an image with FLASH, optimize it, upload on server, then on server side make 4 thumbs and then save.

OR

2) load an image in FLASH, make 4 thumbs and upload them on server.

The thumb resolutions are still variable, so I cant say the sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you are asking everyone to make your decision for you.  That means you don't have enough information to make a decision yet.  Once you understand the problem, you'll know the right solution.  With the information you provided, any "authoritative" answer would be a guess.

For a client implementation:  How much data must be sent to the client to do the image manipulation (i.e. how big is the application)?  What minimum resources would be required of the client machine?  About how long would developing a proof of concept take?  How large of an image would client upload?  What software would the client have to have already installed?  What operating systems will you support?

In a server implementation: what's the max size image the server would accept for manipulation?  How many images is the server expected to handle?  What kind of load is anticipated?  What are similar applications from which load can be inferred?  How long would it take to create a proof of concept?  What amount of server resources would be necessary to perform the work?How will you prevent one user (or a small group of users) from monopolizing the server's resources, but still fulfill their requests in a reasonable time?

Once the POC is created for one, how long would it take to create a POC for the other? What are the testing costs?  If you have to purchase software, what are those costs?  If you are going to use OSS software, are the licenses acceptable?  Will you be creating a derivative work (and does it matter, given the license)?  Same for closed source software - those have licenses, too.

Comment: Well, for the client side FLASH is kind of universal and it runs on almost every machine.

On server side: I really do not know these details but will be used ruby on rails.

The only thing I wanted to know if is more consuming:
1) load an image with FLASH, optimize it, upload on server, then on server side make 4 thumbs and then save.

OR

2) load an image in FLASH, make 4 thumbs and upload them on server.

The thumb resolutions are still variable, so I cant say the sizes.

Comment: You still have to download your flash app to the browser.  How big will this app be?  Which is more important, given your deployment scenario - server resources or client response time?  Will client uploads be fast enough to prevent the clients from browsing away?

More succinctly: why aren't you creating some basic proof of concept code and testing for yourself?  Especially since you don't seem to know the details of your deployment...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you expect to manipulate it client side in a webbrowser unless its some application, anyways image manipulation usually takes place server side. Create a que so everything is organized and works in an organized manner.

Comment: Hy,
On client side with FLASH or (if possible) with just javascript.